# Rails 5: Validates length if field is not blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was trying to work on my Rails model where in if user leave the field blank there will be no validation on the length of phone number, otherwise, if it is not blank and got field out, then there should be validation on the length.

I tried the ff codes but did not work:

```
validates_length_of :phone, minimum: 7, maximum: 15, unless: -> { !:phone.blank? }
```

Any idea how to attain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your looking for `allow_blank: true` option.
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank